# How can I batch convert mkv files to mp4?

Tags: convert, avconv, batch

At moment I use the single video command  of:

```
avconv -i File_name1.mkv -codec copy File_name1.mp4
```

To change format but I need a method to do this for over 400 videos what would the batch command be?

Comment: You should be able to use something like `for i in *.mkv; avconv -i $i -codec copy "$i.mp4"; done` but I can't test it right now.

Answer (score 10):

```
for f in *.mkv; do avconv -i "$f" -codec copy "${f%.mkv}.mp4"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mencoder`. Install with:

```
sudo apt install mencoder
```

then:

```
for f in *.mkv; do mencoder "$f" -o "$f".mp4 -ovc lavc -oac lavc;done
```

The default output formats without any options are MPEG-4 for video and MP2 for audio.
Refer to `man mencoder` for more help.

Answer (score 1):

Try **winFF** which is the gui for FFmgeg to batch convert audit & video files either from software center or;

```
sudo apt-get install winff
```

Comment: I have installed WinFF but it does not like my system for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Another one through `find` command,

```
find /path -name '*.mkv' -exec bash -c 'avconv -i "$1" -codec copy "${1%.mkv}.mp4"' _ {} \;
```